# Xamarin.Android Support Android 4.0 (API 14) and above

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio enterprise 2017 on windows 10. the android demo app is working seemingly well on ***Android 7.1 (API 27) emulator***. however, when I run the app with a ***4.4 Android (API 19) Emulator***, it fails immediately after starting with the following error:

```
Android application is debugging.
Could not connect to the debugger.
12-26 19:37:00.890 D/dalvikvm( 1918): Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-26 19:37:00.922 D/dalvikvm( 1918): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/App5.App5-2/libmonodroid.so 0xa8f90fc0
12-26 19:37:00.922 D/dalvikvm( 1918): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/App5.App5-2/libmonodroid.so 0xa8f90fc0
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Creating public update directory: `/data/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__`
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Using override path: /data/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
12-26 19:37:00.934 W/monodroid( 1918): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
12-26 19:37:00.938 W/monodroid( 1918): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/App5.App5-2/libmonosgen-2.0.so
12-26 19:37:00.938 W/monodroid( 1918): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/App5.App5/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
12-26 19:37:00.938 W/monodroid-debug( 1918): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29360,server=y,embedding=1
12-26 19:37:01.102 W/monodroid-debug( 1918): Accepted stdout connection: 43
12-26 19:37:01.870 D/Mono    ( 1918): Image addref mscorlib[0xb8989ef0] -> mscorlib.dll[0xb8989160]: 2
12-26 19:37:01.870 D/Mono    ( 1918): Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)
12-26 19:37:01.874 D/Mono    ( 1918): AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/App5.App5-2/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
12-26 19:37:01.874 D/Mono    ( 1918): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/App5.App5-2/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
12-26 19:37:01.874 D/Mono    ( 1918): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
12-26 19:37:01.874 D/Mono    ( 1918): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
12-26 19:37:01.890 D/Mono    ( 1918): Assembly mscorlib[0xb8989ef0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
```

the minimum target is set to c4.0. perplexed by the fact that even  `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` requires `MonoAndroid 8.0`, I don't even know where to start... however, I have interchanged/switched around the `target version`, `minimum version`, and `compile version` with no luck. targeting ***Android 4.0 (API 14)*** was even worse as the app could not even build... [The following is the Github code of the working app with minimum version set as Android 4.0, target set as Android 8.0, and compiled with Android 8.0, and running on Android 7.1 emulator](https://github.com/McKabue/CustomAndroidToolBar)

**How do I make my app support Android 4.0 (API 14) without errors on the Android 4.4 emulator?**

Comment: I highly recommend reading over https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/ to get a better understanding why Support libraries require the latest API to compile against.

Comment: As for your question, it is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why your application could not connect to the debugger? Are you asking why support libraries require the latest version to compile against?

Comment: am asking how to make it support Andoid 4.0 (API 14) without errors on emulator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48814/android-api-14-installed-but-missing

API level 14 is no longer supported since Xamarin.Android 5.0, sorry. You have to use API level 15 instead.

[Binding assemblies for Android v1.6 (API-4), Android v2.1 (API-7), Android v2.2 (API-8), Android v3.1 (API-12), and Android v4.0 (API-14) has been dropped. 
Xamarin.Android applications can still run on these platforms, but the compiler will no longer assist you in ensuring that types and members which do not exist in those API levels are not referenced.](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.0/)

what that simply means: ***go find some other home for your hopes...***